# how to set a limited time to my console application

Tags: c#-3.0

I was thinking how to set a limited period on my console application.

For instance, I want to give just 10 seconds to users to choose or do something when they just come in. 
If time exceeds 10 seconds, then the user should get a warning.

Here is my code. I tried to first convert it to string and then to int, but something is wrong...

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace exercise
{
    class Program
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 2000);
            // Wait for the user to hit <Enter>
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
        {
            bool loop = true;                                 // Console.WriteLine("{0:h:mm:ss.fff}.\n", DateTime.Now); ---->     Creating timer
            string b = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            // Display the date/time when this method got called.
            Console.WriteLine("In TimerCallback: " + b);
            int c = Convert.ToInt32(b);
            // Force a garbage collection to occur for this demo.
            if (c == 10000)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" your time is runnig out , hurry up brow");
            }
            GC.Collect();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.ParseExact("2009-05-08 14:40:52,531", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff" 
to pass a string to datetime, but you will parse the datetime, not the amounts of time passed.

You can store the number of calls in a static field and check the 10 seconds that way.

```
class Program
    {
        private static int timerCounter = 1;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 2000);
            // Wait for the user to hit <Enter>
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
        {
            bool loop = true; // Console.WriteLine("{0:h:mm:ss.fff}.\n", DateTime.Now); ---->     Creating timer
            string b = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            // Display the date/time when this method got called.
            Console.WriteLine("In TimerCallback: " + b);

            // timer callback is every 2 seconds, so every 5th call is 10 sec
            if (timerCounter % 5 == 0)
            {
                timerCounter = 1;
                Console.WriteLine(" your time is runnig out , hurry up brow");
            }

            timerCounter++;
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```